# How do I send a message from One fragment to another on a Click of the button from the First one?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have tried this code but clicking a button in First Fragment isn't changing the string value in the Second.

This is the kotlin file of First Fragment. It has two buttons on click of which should change the string value. I have also created an inner interface inside this class which is `OnButtonClickListener`, as mentioned in Android Documentation.

```
viewHolder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_one, container, false)

    viewHolder.btnFragTestOneMessageOne.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onButtonCLickListener("MESSAGE ONE")
    }

    viewHolder.btnFragTestOneMessageTwo.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onButtonCLickListener("MESSAGE TWO")
    }

    return viewHolder
```

This is the second fragment. This fragment's layout also has a textView which has to be changed on the click of a button inside the First fragment.

```
lateinit var viewHolder: View

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    viewHolder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_two, container, false)
    return viewHolder
}
```

And here is the activity file.

```
override fun onButtonCLickListener(strMessage: String) {
    testTwoFragment.viewHolder.tvFragTestTwo.text = strMessage
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_test)

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.flFragTest, TestOneFragment()).commit()

    btnTestFragOne.setOnClickListener {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragTest, testOneFragment).commit()
    }


    btnTestFragTwo.setOnClickListener {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flFragTest, testTwoFragment).commit()
    }

}
```

Comment: what type of message you want to send similar toast or some data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your message in String format then

Use **Bundle** to send String:

```
//Put the value
YourNewFragment ldf = new YourNewFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
ldf.setArguments(args);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

In onCreateView of the new **Fragment**:

```
//Retrieve the value
String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```

Comment: Works fine except that it makes the text defined to the textView in the fragment_layout file empty. But can be rectified using the null checks.

Comment: means you want to set that text to textview ?

Comment: Yes, using this code solved the problem.  `arguments?.getString("msg").run {
            if (this != null)
                viewHolder.tvFragTestTwo.text = this
            else
                viewHolder.tvFragTestTwo.text = "NO BUTTONS CLICKED"
        }`

Comment: @VishakAKamath Thanks for Approving Answer